# Keep individuals in the same firm by year (Stata)

Tags: stata, economics

I have an employer-employee database and need to keep only the individuals that have at least one colleague considering the Firm_id variable, but I don't know how to do this in Stata. My dataset is like this:

```
Id    Firm_id    Year
1        50       2010
1        50       2011
2        50       2010
2        50       2011
3        22       2010
3        22       2011
4        22       2010
4        20       2011
```

In the case above, I would keep only the individuals corresponding to the Id 1 and 2 because they are in the same firm in both of the years in the sample and Id 3 and 4 for 2010.

The output I'm looking for is like:

```
Id    Firm_id    Year
1        50       2010
1        50       2011
2        50       2010
2        50       2011
3        22       2010
4        22       2010
```

Any suggestions on how to perform this in Stata?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bysort Id (Firm_id) : keep if Firm_id[1] == Firm_id[_N]
```

See FAQ [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/listing-observations-in-group/).

Comment: Thank you, Nick. In case of having more years in the sample, does this command work for the same purpose?

Comment: Indeed. The test is that the first and the last values within each group are the same after sorting, and the same code works for any number of observations in a group, including 1, 2, 3, .... See the FAQ cited for the logic.

Comment: Thank you very much again, Nick !